# Represent natural number as sum of distinct squares

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

The problem is to find the largest set S of positive integers such that the sum of the squares of the elements of S is equal to a given number n.

For example:

> 4 = 2²
>   20 = 4² + 2²
>   38 = 5² + 3² + 2²
>   300 = 11² + 8² + 7² + 6² + 4² + 3² + 2² + 1².

I have an algorithm that runs in time `O(2^(sqrt n) * n)`, but it's too slow (every subset of squares).

Comment: So the problem is that you're after a faster algorithm?

Comment: Unfortunately my solution is too slow.

Comment: It just wasn't clear from your question, since you don't mention it at all.

Comment: The example you gave is wrong. 300 can be written as 11² + 8² + 7² + 6² + 4² + 3² + 2² + 1².

Comment: OP, are you familiar with *dynamic programming*? You can read about it in any good algorithms book.

Comment: By the way, not all numbers can be written as a sum of distinct squares. For example 6 or 2.

Comment: If anyone is interested, [strongly connected topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1006621/186012) on mathSE. I can't prove that problems are equal, so I didn't put it (using this observation solution) as an answer. Maybe I'll do it in future. If my assumptions are true, it is possible to solve in `O(N*lg(n))`, where N is number of squares in sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an `O(n^1.5)`-time algorithm based on the canonical dynamic program for [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). Here's the recurrence:

```
C(m, k) is the size of the largest subset of 1..k whose squares sum to m
C(m, k), m < 0 = -infinity (infeasible)
C(0, k) = 0
C(m, 0), m > 0 = -infinity (infeasible)
C(m, k), m > 0, k > 0 = max(C(m, k-1), C(m - k^2, k-1) + 1)
```

Compute `C(m, k)` for all `m` in `0..n` and all `k` in `0..floor(n^0.5)`. Return `C(n, floor(n^0.5))` for the objective value. To recover the set, trace back the argmaxes.

Answer (score 4):

I was just wondering if this problem reduce to NP? Looks like you have list of integers (squares) less than `n` (could be generated in `O(sqrt(n))`) and you're looking for subset sum of size from `1 to sqrt(n)` (check all posibilities). If so it should be solvable with knapsack dynamic programming algorithm (but this is pretty naive algorithm and I think it could be improved) in `O(n^2)` - sqrt(n) of problems to check times sqrt(n) knapsack items count times n knapsack weight.

EDIT:
I think with smart backtracking after filling dynamic programming array you could do it in `O(n*sqrt(n))`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the recurrence:

```
T(0, m) = 0
T(n, m) = -Infinity (if n<0 or m<0)
T(n, m) = max(T(n-m*m, m-1)+1, T(n, m-1))
```

Or, in Python code:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(100000)
def T(n, m):
    if n<0 or m<0: return (-1000000, 0)
    if n==0: return (0, 0)
    return max((T(n-m*m, m-1)[0]+1, m), T(n, m-1)) 

def squares(n):
    s = int(n**0.5)
    while n>0 and s>0:
        _, factor = T(n, s)
        yield factor**2
        n -= factor**2
        s = factor-1

for x in (4, 20, 38, 300):
    result = list(squares(x))
    print(sum(result), '= sum', result)
```

The example you gave (300), can be written with 8 factors as:

300 = 11² + 8² + 7² + 6² + 4² + 3² + 2² + 1²

Other results:

```
4 = sum [4]
20 = sum [16, 4]
38 = sum [25, 9, 4]
300 = sum [121, 64, 49, 36, 16, 9, 4, 1]
```