# Sum of squares function in Python?

Tags: python, numbers

In Mathematica, there's a function called SquaresR that determines the number of summing k square integers to equal some specific natural number n:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html

I have looked online for a Python package including a similar function and found nothing. Is there a Python implementation somewhere out there? (If it helps, I only need it for k=3).

If not, is there a more efficient method to implement it than brute force?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26222693/2454357) of any help?

Comment: Similar in principle, but not what I need and I don't see any way it can be used for this problem.

Comment: I think it's treated in : http://web.mit.edu/rsi/www/pdfs/papers/98/atievsky.pdf (Oops, tried to read it, get coffee first...)