# Sum of squares of distinct integers

Tags: algorithm

Could you please suggest any algorithm ideas for solving the following problem:

> Given positive integers *S*, *K* ≤ *N*. Find distinct positive integers *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>2</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>*K*</sub> such that
>
> *x*<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + *x*<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + *x*<sub>*K*</sub><sup>2</sup> = *S*
>
> *x*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *N* and *x*<sub>*i*</sub> < *x*<sub>*i*+1</sub> for all *i* = 1...*K*.

So far I know that I should start searching for the largest *x* below the square root of *S*.

Comment: Every positive number can be written as a sum of at most 4 squares. See for instance the answer I have given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556521/5459839) which gives an implementation for finding *x1, x2, x3 and x4* (or fewer).

Comment: @trincot thanks for this, my case is a bit different, because integers should be distinct, which is not case for 4-square theorem, but thanks for direction to think

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Represent natural number as sum of distinct squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26222693/represent-natural-number-as-sum-of-distinct-squares)

Comment: it's not a duplicate thereof, the constraints are different

Comment: I don't understand the role of N in the question. Any xᵢ will be ≤ S, so that xᵢ ≤ N will always be true. So why mention an N at all? Couldn't the problem simply be stated as “Given positive integers S and K, find [...]” omitting the “xᵢ ≤ N and” part?

Comment: @WalterTross sure N matters. For example, there are 3 ways to sum to 178 from 5 positive integers. But there are only two if we restrict the largest integer to 10.

Comment: I assumed S, K ≤ N means S ≤ N and K ≤ N, but it seems I was wrong. I would rephrase the problem as "given positive integers S, K and N, with K ≤ N [...]", then.

Comment: @WalterTross ha, I totally misread it, lol!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly optimised brute force. As I linked to in the comments (and close vote), it seems to me we could modify the standard subset sum problem to work with squares.

JavaScript code (ellipsis at the end of an output means add the rest of the numbers down to 1):

```js
function f(S, K, N){
  function g(s, k, n, c){
    const minS = k*(k+1)*(2*k+1)/6;
    const maxN = Math.min(
      n,
      ~~Math.sqrt(s - (k-1)*k*(2*k-1)/6)
    );

    if (s < minS || maxN < 1)
      return [];
    else if (s == minS)
      return [c.concat([k, '...'])];
    if (k == 0)
      return [];
    
    return g(s - maxN*maxN, k - 1, maxN - 1, c.slice().concat(maxN))
      .concat(
        g(s, k, maxN - 1, c)
      );
  }
  
  return g(S, K, N, []);
}

for (let j=1; j<6; j++)
  console.log(JSON.stringify([178, j, f(178, j, 100)]));

console.log(JSON.stringify([178, 5, f(178, 5, 10)]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you ask for an **algorithm idea**, and not a precise answer, so here is my 2 cents.

You can transform your problem to get rid of the squares by finding all perfect squares ( e.g. `1, 4, 9, 16, 25...`) from `1` to `S` and put them into a set called `PerfectSquareSetLessThanS`.

Then, if you can solve the following (more general) problem, you can easily solve your original problem.

General problem:

Given an arbitary set `V`, find a subset `W` of `V` that has exactly `K` numbers such that they sum to `S`.

While I don't yet have a precise solution, your general problem looks a lot like a well known problem called the [3SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) problem.

The 3SUM problem asks if given a set of `n` numbers, are there a set of 3 numbers whose sum is 0. The wikipedia page outlines an algorithm to search for such tupple.

Note that the 3SUM problems have different variants, 1 of which is the k-SUM (substitute 3 by k in the above paragraph) , and another one is the non-zero sum variant. Maybe you could find a combination of these two variants to build your generalized solution.